# Apply affine transformation to multiple layers

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, batch, affine-transformation

I have many shapefiles representing the layers of a map (roads, buildings, etc). In total, I have hundred of layers, and I want to scale all of them by the same factor. I know I can use the affine transformation plugin to do that, but I was looking for an automatic way to do all 100+ layers to avoid having to do it manually every time.

Is there any such thing?

Comment: Do you need other parameters than just scale x and scale y?  If not, with the SpatiaLite's ScaleCoordinates function it should be simple https://www.gaia-gis.it/gaia-sins/spatialite-sql-latest.html. You could use ogr2ogr with -sql parameter and make a script for the batch process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the GRASS tool **v.transform** and run it as a **batch** process. The tool is described as:

> "v.transform - Performs an affine transformation (shift, scale and rotate) on vector map."

---

You can find this in:

```
Processing Toolbox > GRASS commands > Vector (v.*) > v.transform
```

And then right-click to bring up the options:

[image: Batch process]

---

**EDIT:**

If you want to have the fields automatically filled in, you can...

1. Create a **model** from:

   ```
   Processing Toolbox > Models > Tools > Create new model
   ```
2. Then add a *Vector layer* from the `Input` tab and give it a name (e.g. "layer"):

   [image: Input parameter]
3. Then go to the `Algorithms` tab and find the `v.transform` tool:

   [image: Algorithm parameter]
4. Fill in the fields with the relevant settings and an output name (e.g. "result"):

   [image: v.transform settings]
5. Make sure to give a name to the model and group:

   [image: Save names]
6. Save the model and close the model window. Then find your model in the *Processing Toolbox* and right-click to execute it as a batch process:

   [image: Run model as batch process]
7. Click the ellipsis button for the top row only the input and select all your input layers (either those already loaded into QGIS or from a directory). Then again from the top row, click the ellipsis button for the result:

   [image: Load and save files]
8. Select a directory to save the output files and add a name that you will use as a prefix to the original file name. I.e. if I use "Result_for_" then all my output files will begin with "Result_for_" followed by the original file name:

   [image: Add prefix name]
9. When you click *Save*, another pop-up box will appear, use the `Fill with parameter values` for the **Autofill mode**:

   [image: Fill parameter values]
10. ***Finally***, you should see the output names of the results which will be produced when you **run** the model:

    [image: Model ready]

Comment: I don't see the GRASS GIS commands. I also tried looking for a plugin with that name but I couldn't find anything. I'm on Ubuntu, using QGIS 2.8.6-Wien

Comment: Eventually I found out that is a common problem of incompatible libraries. So now I have the batch screen in front of me, where I can set the parameters for each transformation. However, I don't want to copy/paste the values of the Xscale, Yscale (..etc) for all of the layers. This kind of defeats the purpose of running them altogether... is there a way to automatically fill all the fields?

Comment: @someoneElse - Glad you found it eventually (also, at the bottom of the of the _Processing Toolbox_ interface, is it set to **Advanced interface**?). I've edited my post to include how to create a model which would have you only enter the parameters once and run it on all your layers :)